# Mock CosmosClient in Java junits

Tags: java, azure, unit-testing, cosmosclient

We have a requirement where we are fetching few records from Azure-CosmosDB - sql api
For increasing coverage, we want to mock but have searched a lot but didn't find for Java.
Could you please guide here

My DAO class is as below

```
private CosmosClient client;

@Autowired
public DAO(CosmosClient client) {
    this.client = client;
}

CosmosDatabase database;
CosmosContainer container;

    private static final String DATABASE = "test-db";
    private static final String CONTAINER = "test-container";

   /**
     * Test method
     */
    public List<TestVO> fetchTestData() {

       // create database
        CosmosDatabaseResponse databaseResponse = client.createDatabaseIfNotExists(DATABASE);
        database = client.getDatabase(databaseResponse.getProperties().getId());

      // create container
        CosmosContainerProperties containerProperties = new CosmosContainerProperties(CONTAINER, "/pkey");
        CosmosContainerResponse containerResponse = database.createContainerIfNotExists(containerProperties,
                throughputProperties);
        container = database.getContainer(containerResponse.getProperties().getId());

           // Form querySpec
            Iterable<FeedResponse<Test>> feedRespIter = container
                    .queryItems(querySpec, queryOptions, Test.class).iterableByPage(continuationToken, pageSize);

            // iterate list of documents to return shipping list
            if (feedRespIter .iterator().hasNext()) {
                // Some business logic
            }
    }
```

On injecting mock to cosmosClient or just mocking, I get error

```
Cannot mock/spy class com.azure.cosmos.CosmosClient
Mockito cannot mock/spy because
 - final class
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.initMocks(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:60)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CosmosClient is a final class, and to mock final classes, you need to configure a Mockito feature using the below steps:

Create a file in the following path:

```
src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
```

with the following content:

```
mock-maker-inline
```

This should enable Mocking of final classes.